# SPFx web part shrinking when deployed and in workbench

Tags: web-part, spfx, modern-pages

My custom web part is no where near the actual size of the application when I do `gulp serve`, and the same happens when I deploy the web part to the App catalog. I've tried looking for answers online, but none of them has worked so far. The main one I've tried is:

```
      #workbenchPageContent,
  .CanvasComponent.LCS .CanvasZone {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
```

The size of the web part used to be normal in the past, because if I restore an old .sppkg version it uses the full size of the page. I assume its not possible to decode the .sppkg file to take a look and see what changed?

Comment: You can change extension of the sppkg file to zip and then you can extract it and there inside **ClientSideAssets** folder you can find one javascript file where you can check css applied. You can seach in javascript by css class name.

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela I tried this, but its not really that easy to distinguish the CSS part of it. Do you know of any other fixes that might work for the shrinking issue?